# How to make a fire whirl like in the movie

Tags: cycles-render-engine

how can I make a fire whirl like in the movie "into the storm"...?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbCUGTzFWtk --> from 0:30 so that the under part is on fire and the higher part of the tornado is only smoke... :D

Comment: What have you tried and with specifically what you have problem/need help with? The question is very broad. You are asking for a full-fledged tutorial that could occupy 4 pages in a magazine or an hour long video. Narrowing it down would help a lot.

Comment: I know hot to make a tornado but the big problem is, I dont know how I can do it, that a part of particles are emitting smoke and some fire...

Comment: Having a tornado from particles is good start. From this flamethrower tutorial you can learn how to make particles emit smoke: https://vimeo.com/23856096. And from this one how to make a volumetric fire shader: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opfzcNY2u5A. The thing is fire and smoke are not 2 things, it's the same smoke, but the hot smoke just emits light. And this is all handled inside the shader based of the *Flame* atribute of the smoke.